# Usage of rename function with paste in a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, tidyverse

I am coding a for loop to import 6 dataframes and applying to them certain treatments.

```
b = 6
for (i in 1:b) {
  a = as.numeric(20200518)
  d = as.Date("2020-05-18")

  assign(paste("vacantes_", a + i, sep = ""), read_excel(paste("Favorites/Tito/01. aaaaaa/aaaaaaa 20/05. Data/
         01. aa/01. Módulo aaaaaaaaaaa/Vacante_inconsistencias_", a + i, ".xlsx", sep = ""),col_names = TRUE))

  assign(paste("vacantes_", a + i, "_llenado", sep = ""), get(paste("vacantes_", a + i, sep = "")) %>% 
         select("ddd", "uuuu", Llenó", "cod") %>% 
         group_by(ddd, uuuu, `Llenó`) %>% summarise(Cantidad = n()))

  assign(paste("vacantes_", a + i, "_llenado1", sep = ""), 
         dcast(get(paste("vacantes_", a + i, "_llenado", sep = "")), ddd + uuuu ~ `Llenó`, sum) %>% 
         mutate(Fecha = as.Date(d + i)) %>% select("Fecha", "ddd", "uuuu", "NO", "SÍ"))

  if(i == b){
    rm(a, b, i, d)
  }
}
```

In the last process `Cast` (third function), I wanted to rename two columns in each dataframe so I add the last line to that part of the code:

```
## Cast  
assign(paste("vacantes_", a + i, "_llenado1", sep = ""), 
    dcast(get(paste("vacantes_", a + i, "_llenado", sep = "")), ddd + uuuu ~ `Llenó`, sum) %>% 
    mutate(Fecha = as.Date(d + i)) %>% select("Fecha", "ddd", "uuuu", "NO", "SÍ") %>% 
    rename(paste("NO_", a + 1, sep ="") = NO, paste("SI_", a + 1, sep ="") = SÍ))
```

The rename function causes the for loop to not work at all. I got:

```
Error: inesperado '=' in:
" i, "_llenado1", sep = ""), dcast(get(paste("vacantes_", a + i, "_llenado", sep = "")), ddd + uuuu ~ `Llenó`, sum) %>% 
    mutate(Fecha = as.Date(d + i)) %>% select("Fecha", "ddd", "uuuu", "NO", "SÍ")) %>% rename_(paste("NO_", a + 1, sep ="") ="
```

I tried adding `rename(get(paste("NO_", a + 1, sep ="")) = NO, get(paste("SI_", a + 1, sep ="")) = SÍ)` but it doesn't work either.

Just to clarify, I removed the `rename` line and the for loop worked as I wanted so far so that line of code is the problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we are using `paste`, then an option is to assign (`:=`) while evaluating (`!!`)

```
library(dplyr)
head(mtcars) %>% 
      rename(!!paste0('NO_', 2) := mpg, 'SI' = carb)
#                  NO_2 cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear SI
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4  4
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4  4
#Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4  1
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3  1
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3  2
#Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3  1
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add a sample of your data e.g. with `dput`. Would it not be easier to read all these data objects into a list:

```
path <- "./files"
files <- list.files(path = path,
                    full.names = TRUE,
                    all.files = FALSE)
files <- files[!file.info(files)$isdir]

data <- lapply(files,
               function(x) {
                 read_excel(x, ,col_names = TRUE)
               })
```

And then apply whatever data transformation you require? You can do this by using `lapply` in combination with your transformation function. Or you can `bind_rows` the lot together and use your `dplyr` verbs to do the transformation.